# I´m having the error #1241 in MySql when I try this syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I´m getting this error

> 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

when I try to select these two tables and columns.

I tried to remove the () from the select but that didn't work.

```
  SELECT (SELECT (SUM(preco_base),0)   FROM produtos) +
         (SELECT (SUM(salario_base),0) FROM salarios)
    FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: SUM only takes one argument; perhaps what you need is more like `IFNULL(SUM(preco_base), 0)`

Comment: Try this: `SELECT (SELECT SUM(preco_base) FROM produtos) + (SELECT SUM(salario_base) FROM salarios) FROM DUAL;`

Comment: Thanks, its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sum()   contanin a single operand sum(acol)  not sum(col, 0)

You could try using a croos join

```
select a.sum_preco_base + b.sum_salario_base 
from (
 SELECT SUM(preco_base) sum_preco_base
  FROM produtos 
) a 
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT (SUM(salario_base) sum_salario_base
  FROM salarios
) b
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
select a.sum_pb + b.sum_sb
from (select sum(preco_base) sum_pb from produtos) a,
     (select sum(salario_base) sum_sb from salarios) b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT (COALESCE( (SELECT SUM(preco_base) FROM produtos), 0) +
        COALESCE( (SELECT SUM(salario_base) FROM salarios), 0)
       )
```

`dual` is not necessary and you want to `COALESCE()` *after* the subquery has run.